# Why can't I override the base region.html.twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I created a custom theme that has the `bootstrap_barrio` contrib theme as `base theme`. Everything is setup and working except that my custom `region--content.html.twig` in the /templates folder of my custom theme isn't being picked up. Drupal continues to use the base `region--nowrap.html.twig` that came with bootstrap_barrio. My custom template shows up in the list of template suggestions when twig debugging is on.

I thought all I needed to do to override a base template was create a custom template into the custom theme, rebuild cache and Drupal will pick it up, as long as it conforms to the theme hook suggestions naming convention.

**Twig Debugging Output:**

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'region' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x region--nowrap.html.twig
   * region--content.html.twig
   * region.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap_barrio/templates/layout/region--nowrap.html.twig' -->
```

Comment: Please share the full list of theme suggestions.  It could be that your custom template is not specific enough.  To test this, copy the exact same template `region--nowrap.html.twig` from `bootstrap_barrio` into your theme, modify it with a "I AM HERE" text or something, rebuild caches, and see if Drupal picks it up.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Done. When I copy same base `region--nowrap.html.twig` into custom theme, Drupal does pick it up. It just doesn't do the same for `region--content.html.twig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. Apparently if you have active "Clean wrapper for (x region)" on your theme, it will use that damn nowrap template no matter what. Disabling that goes back to use your default theme templates. You can find it over: /admin/appearance/settings/themeName
Screenshot to follow:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `x` in the twig debugging indicates the *active* template.  Twig always goes from most specific (top of list) to least specific (bottom of list).  So, for this order:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x region--nowrap.html.twig
   * region--content.html.twig
   * region.html.twig
-->
```

If `region--nowrap.html.twig` is present in the current theme or any of the parent themes, it will be given priority over any of the "lower" files.

In your case, You can confirm this by renaming `region--nowrap.html.twig` in the parent theme; this should cause `region--content.html.twig` in your subtheme to be given priority.

Solution: Override `region--nowrap.html.twig`, not `region--content.html.twig`.

Comment: Thing is: `region--nowrap.html.twig` is used as the generic template across all regions, though I don't see how it conforms to theme naming-suggestions. There's no region actually named "nowrap", so I don't understand why `region--nowrap.html.twig` is the preferred by Drupal. Overriding `region--nowrap.html.twig` will affect all regions than the "content" region I'm trying to affect

Comment: @okey_on This is probably an issue with Barrio then.  I downloaded Barrio 5.1 and checked the `region--nowrap.html.twig`, which states in the header `Bartik's theme implementation to display a header region`.  So devs just cut-and-paste this file from Bartik.  According to the comment, that region should be applied to the header only, not every region on the page.  As noted in that comment, use of this template is controlled by `hook_preprocess_region()`.  You can find `bootstrap_barrio_preprocess_region()` in `bootstrap_barrio.theme`.